# wp_mail() + Ajax + ValidationEngine + $wpdb->insert

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, forms

I decided to ask this question because there is no simple answer to it.
I have a contact form in my home.php which looks like:

HTML:

```
<form id="js-calculator" name="calculator" action="" method="post">
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
     <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
     <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
     <label for="accept"><input class="" type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" /> I agree to terms and conditions</label>
     <button type="submit" id="send__btn">Wyślij wycenę</button></p>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#js-calculator').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php") ?>',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: $this.serialize()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP in functions.php

```
  // Function to send emails
  function sendMail () {
    $subject = 'Automatic evaluation';
    $headers = 'From: My Website Contact Form <contact@mysite.com>';
    $send_to = "office@mysite.com, ". $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Evaluation for ". $_POST['name'];
    $message = "Message from ".$_POST['message'];
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_sendhtmlmail', 'sendMail');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendhtmlmail', 'sendMail');

  add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
  function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
  }

  // Function to update DB
  function addCustomer(){
  global $wpdb;

  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $accept = $_POST['accept'];

  if($wpdb->insert('customers',array(
    'phone'=>$phone,
    'email'=>$email,
    'accept'=>$accept
  ))===FALSE){
  echo "Error";
} else {
  $wpdb->insert_id;    
}
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
```

What I would like to achive is:
1. Send an HTML email to client and to website admin, 
2. Add client details to Database, check if email exists,
3. Have a secure connections and data flow;

Right now I have no idea what I`ve done wrong... Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes you are right @KirkBeard, I need to update whole question.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, couple of things:

In your JS ajax call, you need to specify the action to call, here's modified call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#js-calculator').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php?action=sendhtmlmail") ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $this.serialize()
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Now, lets look at the php functions:

```
// Function to send emails
function sendMail () {
  $data = array(
    'email' = sanitize_email($_POST['email']),
    'name' = sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']),
    'message' = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']),
  );
  $subject = 'Automatic evaluation;
  $headers = 'From: My Website Contact Form <contact@mysite.com>';
  $send_to = "office@mysite.com, ". $data['email'];
  $subject = "Evaluation for ". $data['name'];
  $message = "Message from ".$data['message'];
  wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  addCustomer($data);
  // TODO: Fill in this $response array with meaninfull data (check output from wp_mail and addCustomer)
  $response = array(
    'success' => true
  );
  wp_send_json($response);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_sendhtmlmail', 'sendMail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendhtmlmail', 'sendMail');
```

Just missing the wp_mail call, and the cleanup of the inputs, I removed your other ajax call, and have the sendMail function just pass the data to the addCustomer function. You'll notice a wp_send_json call, this is to send the response to the JS. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json

Now lets look at your addCustomer function:

```
// Function to update DB
function addCustomer($data){
  global $wpdb;

  $phone = $data['phone'];
  $email = $data['email'];
  $accept = $data['accept'];

  if($wpdb->insert('customers',array(
      'phone'=>$phone,
      'email'=>$email,
      'accept'=>$accept
    ))===FALSE){
    return false;
  } else {
    return $wpdb->insert_id;
  }
}
```

The only thing that change here, is the return, so that the caller knows if it failed.

To handle inputs from user, check this doc from wordpress and core functions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

---

Or you could use the following plugins together:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/

Here's how to use it: https://contactform7.com/save-submitted-messages-with-flamingo/

I hope this helps you!
Regards,

P.S wordpress questions are better suited here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Chasing right now, I`ll let you know. Cheers